# In Android how to show a popup when post share is complete

Tags: android, android-intent, share, android-alertdialog, shareactionprovider

I have ShareActionProvider in my Application. it shares a photo I uploaded with a text I insert. When share is done, I want to show a popup message/dialog with a button OK, clicking on which I should return to my application. The question is: in my application how can I know if share is complete or no ? For example, if I share the photo and text in instagram, how can I know that post is already done.

Comment: Please explain, in detail, what "share is complete" means.

Comment: I will edit my question now.

Comment: you are getting the response when your post is successfully posted . check it carefully .

Answer (score 3):

> in my application how can I know if share is complete or no ? For example, if I share the photo and text in instagram, how can I know that post is already done.

That is not possible for `ACTION_SEND`. What the user does with the shared content in the other app is between the user and the developers of the other app. The user might do something immediately, later, or never. The app might do something immediately or later (e.g., upload the content as part of a periodic sync operation with a server). There is no protocol for the receiving app to tell you that sharing is "done".

Specific apps may offer specific APIs, beyond `ACTION_SEND`, that offer capabilities in this area, but those will be unique to those apps.

Answer (score 1):

Use a Toast like this: `Toast.make(context "Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Toast is just tiny little "popup"

Comment: The question is: in my application how can I know if share is complete or no ? for example, if I share the photo and text in instagram, how can I know that post is already done.

Comment: you should make some boolean checks or a custom method that return true if the upload is complete and only if the upload is true, you start the toast. This is just a loose idea for you

Comment: okay, but how can I get that data - upload is true. it's in another application. (instagram, twitter, etc)